# correct way to parse serial port data?

Tags: c#, wpf, stream, serial-port

I'm testing out a program right now that is supposed to receive data from a serial port and parse it, and continually update certain variables tied to that parsed data. I'm having trouble with the actual parsing itself.

The data string output of the port I'm using is: 8 data bits, 1 start bit, 1 stop bit, and no parity. A message starts with the colon symbol : and ends with . An example - : 3.00 20.45 2355 1000 554

**First question:** Is there any method for setting the start bit? I know there's a .StopBits which I have equal to StopBits.One, but I haven't found anything for a start bit.

**In regards to the parsing-**

In the code method below:

```
    serial.DataReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Receive);

    private void Receive(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Collecting the characters received to our 'buffer' (string).
        received_Data = serial.ReadExisting();

    }
```

Would the best way be to set up a string array = received_Data.Split, then use a for loop to go through each "split" and assign it to the correct variable? I've never worked with ports before so this is all new to me. After looking around there seems to be several ways to do this, not sure what the best way would be though.

Comment: Any serial port "parsing" problem starts with ReadExisting().  You only get 1 or 2 characters.  You have to write the code to collect the entire response, then parse it.  So it shouldn't be =, you need +=

Comment: Sorry I do have that, I'll edit my post to show.